# RegEx: matching email addresses with subdomains for GApps

Tags: regex, gmail

I am trying to write a regex that works in Google Apps that matches email addresses on incoming messages with subdomains, e.g.:

```
root@*wildcard*.mydomain.com
```

but not

```
root@mydomain.com
```

So that I can use Gmail to redirect them to the proper recipient @mydomain.com.

The following regex works in my regex editor but doesn't match anything in Gmail testing:

```
^[-+.0-9A-Z_a-z]+@[-+.0-9A-Z_a-z]+\.(mydomain.com)$
```

For those of you familiar with GApps, I'm referring to the setting under Settings > Email > Receiving routing > Configure > Options.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but I think `(mydomain.com)` should be `(mydomain\.com)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the dash last; some regex dialects can't handle a leading dash in a character class. Other than that, your regex looks OK.

```
^[+.0-9A-Z_a-z-]+@[+.0-9A-Z_a-z-]+\.(mydomain\.com)$
```